# Oracle trigger to update table with current row state

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, timestamp

I have a table in `Oracle` with `Timestamp` field, a key field and 2 other columns. Am looking to create a `trigger` which would update another table with just the current state row data based on key, timestamp. Am new to trigger, any inputs and / or recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace TRIGGER A
AFTER INSERT
ON A1
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
BEGIN

UPDATE C SET COLC=:new.colc, D=:new.cold, TIMESTAMP=:new.timestamp WHERE KEY=:new.key;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
   -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
   RAISE;
END A;
```